# EJS template not rendering any data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am having a problem with ejs templates. I've already worked with it in another project and it worked but in this one it doesn't seem to work all it shows is a blank page and it does not render the cards with the passed data. Here is my "view products" route code and my html code for "viewproducts.ejs".

**view products route:**

```
app.get('/viewproducts', function (req, res) {
  var names = [];
  var prices = [];
  var descriptions = [];
  var product = [];
  var length;
  Product.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      length = products.length;
      names = products.map(function (i) {
        return i.name;
      });
      prices = products.map(function (i) {
        return i.price;
      });
      descriptions = products.map(function (i) {
        return i.description;
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      product.push({
        name: names[i],
        description: descriptions[i],
        price: prices[i],
      });
    }
    console.log(product);
  });
  res.render('viewproducts', { artisanproduct: product });
});
```

**viewproducts.ejs**

```
<body>
    <% artisanproduct.forEach((product)=>{ %>
    <div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="w-100"src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <h5 class="card-title"><%=product.name%></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><%=product.description%></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2><%=product.price%><span>MAD</span></h2>
    <button type="submit">BUY</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<%})%>
  </body>
```

Comment: your ejs file has an extra closing div tags and closing form tag

Comment: I removed them. It does not affect the code. Still not rendering any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `res.render()` BEFORE you've collected any data for it.  `Product.find()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  So, to use its result, your code has to be inside its callback or in a function you call from that callback.  Change and simplify to this:

```
app.get('/viewproducts', function (req, res) {
  Product.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);    // send error response
      return;
    }
    const product = products.map(item => {
        return {
          name: item.name,
          price: item.price,
          description: item.description
        };
    });
    res.render('viewproducts', { artisanproduct: product });
  });
});
```

Summary of changes:

1. Move `res.render()` inside the `Product.find()` callback so it has access to that data.
2. Build product array in one `.map()` instead of many.
3. Send error response when there's an error.
4. Use `const` or `let` instead of `var`.
5. Remove unnecessary temporary arrays and temporary variables.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, it worked.